# Storing awk command matched pattern output lines into array indexes

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

I have a file where i am searching for 2 patterns if matched then storing each matched line into array value. **But It is not storing values**

**My Shell command**

```
#Removing new line chars
a=`sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' sample.txt`
#storing each matched pattern row by row 
while read v1; do
y[i]="$v1"
(( i++ ))
done < <(awk -F '<abc>|</abc>' '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) print $i}' <<< "$a")
```

**Outputs empty values:**

```
echo ${y[0]} is empty
echo ${y[1]} is empty
echo ${y[2]} is empty
```

**it should be**

```
echo ${y[0]} = 1. I am here to show
echo ${y[1]} = 2. I am here to show
echo ${y[2]} = 3. I am here to show
```

**My file is : sample.txt**

```
<abc>
1. I am here to show
</abc>
<no>
</no>
<abc>
2. I am here to show
</abc>
<abc>
3. I am here to show
</abc>
<no>
</no>
```

Comment: Using a XML parser would make life much easier.

Comment: @devnull : No dont need xml parser. because it is not an xml file. it is text file. It may or may not have xml tags. in this example, i am searching for tags. if it is present then i need to store accordingly

Comment: I have no idea what your `sed` is doing, but if it is what the comment says, you can remove newlines much more simply with... tr -d '\n' < yourfile

Comment: The sed will only work with GNU sed. Are you using GNU sed?

Comment: @Scrutinizer , DevNull : See my answer ! I have gone mad !

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bit easier on the eye maybe:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a y
while read x; do
   y[i]=$x
   ((i++))
done <  <(awk '/^<abc>/   {p=1;next}
               /^<\/abc>/ {p=0;next} p' sample.txt)
echo ${y[*]}
```

In the `awk`, the variable `p` determines if we are printing the current line. It is set when we find `<abc>` and cleared when we find `</abc>`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem myself...

variable `$i` was already set to some value so when i do i++ it was storing the value in to some  array index.

i did `i=0` then re executed, **it works**